# Try and catch blocks: whether in the class itself or when I call the method outside the class

Tags: java

Could you help me understand where should I throw exceptions and catch them.
Please, have a look at my code. I thought that in Thrd class I have already thrown and caught the exception. But when I wrote in the main class FirstThread.readFile("ParallelProgramming.txt");, I faced a runtime error - unhandled exception. So, I had to use try and catch. So, I somehow can't understand why in the Thd class my try and catch blocks didn't work.

```
package parallelprogramming;

import java.lang.Thread;
import java.io.*;

public class Thrd extends Thread {

    public void readFile(String File) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(File);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;
        try {
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            fr.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException FNFD) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
        catch (IOException IOE){
            System.out.println("IOException caught!");
        }        
    }
}

package parallelprogramming;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ParallelProgramming {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Thrd FirstThread = new Thrd();
        try {
            FirstThread.readFile("ParallelProgramming.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException FNFD) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The general rule is: if you can handle the exception correctly, then catch it, otherwise, let it bubble. But the answer also depends on whether you really want to do parallel programming or not. Your code executes in a single thread: the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules with *checked* exceptions (and this includes `IOException`, which `FileNotFoundException` is a child of), are as follows:

- if you cannot, or do not want, to handle it in your current method, declare that the method `throws` it;
- if you want to handle it in your current method, then `catch` it; note that even in this case you can *rethrow* that exception;
- if `main()` throws any exception, and this exception triggers, the program terminates.

Now, we suppose that you are using Java 7. In this case, do that:

```
public void readFile(final String file)
    throws IOException
{
    final Path path = Paths.get(file);
    for (final String line: Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

Why bother? ;)

If you don't want to do that but read line by line, then:

```
public void readFile(final String file)
    throws IOException
{
    final Path path = Paths.get(file);
    try (
        final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

The second form is preferred if you wish to treat exceptions specifically. Note that with Java 7, you have meaningful exceptions as to why you cannot access the file vs `IOException`: `NoSuchFileException`, `AccessDeniedException`, etc etc. All these inherit `FileSystemException`. The old file API can't do that for you.

This means that if you want to deal with filesystem level errors you can do:

```
catch (FileSystemException e) { /* ... */ }
```

where before that you did:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) { /* ... */ }
```

Translated to the code above, if you want to catch exceptions you'll then do:

```
// All exceptions handled within the method -- except if you rethrow it
public void readFile(final String file)
{
    final Path path = Paths.get(file);
    try (
        final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
    } catch (FileSystemException e) {
        // deal with a filesystem-level error
        // Note that you MUSt catch it before IOException
        // since FileSystemException inherits IOException
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // deal with a low-level I/O error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove '**throws FileNotFoundException**' from the `readFile` method of class `Thrd` then you dont need to handle this exception in main method of class `ParallelProgramming`.

As you throw FileNotFoundException from readFile method then exception will pass to the method will called this i.e. then main method need to handle this exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle an exception either you need to catch it or throw it again.
In the readFile method you have done both. you caught the exceptions using catch blocks then you have mentioned that readFile method throws FileNotFoundException, so when ever you use readFile method you need to catch the exception again.

Comment: Well, I have to digest it a little.